# python search a string in a text file and copy a block

Tags: python, file, search, text, copy

I have this text file names.txt

```
Daniel
Sam
Sameer
Code
Print
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
```

and I want to search it for string "Alpha" and copy the line "alpha" and the previous 100 lines then write"append" it to file result.txt

```
 with open(names.txt) as g:
    lines = (g.readlines())
    for line in lines:
        if "{0}".format("Alpha") in line:
          ????????????
```

I writed this code and stopped here , any one could help ?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? Or are you just asking for a solution in general

Comment: @Parker I don't what to do next and i am new at python i really don't know what to write next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to maintain a list of the last 100 lines you've read, then output them to your `result.txt` file if the current line is `'Alpha'`:

```
limit = 100
prev_items = []

# Open file and iterate over lines.
with open('names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Add the current line to the list.
        prev_items.append(line)
        # Reduce the list to its newest elements.
        prev_items = prev_items[-limit:]

        # If the current line is 'Alpha', we don't need to read any more.
        if line == 'Alpha':
           break

# Append prev_items to the results file.
with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(prev_items))
```

Or, if you're happy to use a collection other than `list`, use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

limit = 100
prev_items = deque(maxlen=limit)

# Open file and iterate over lines.
with open('names.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Add the line to the deque.
        prev_items.append(line)

        # If the current line is 'Alpha', we don't need to read any more.
        if line == 'Alpha':
           break

# Append prev_items to the results file.
with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(prev_items))
```

Comment: Thanks , Your code is perfectly working . Just one more thing could yo tell what i nned to change in the code to change the 100 to a variable in this code ?

Comment: @Mohammed: I've added a `limit` variable to do what you need - just adjust accordingly. (I also changed `prev100` to `prev_items` because it may not have 100 items anymore).

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter to tell you which line had `Alpha` in it, so you can then go back and get the 100 lines before it that you need.